# Could not find com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:3.0.0

Tags: android, android-studio, quickblox, quickblox-android

Android Quickblox Demo App unable to run while sync it always shows error  "Could not find com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:3.0.0."

**Error** :

```
Required by:
project :sample-custom-objects
Could not find com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:3.0.0.
Searched in the following locations:
file:/O:/AndroidSDK-2.3.3/extras/m2repository/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.0.0/baseLibrary-3.0.0.pom
file:/O:/AndroidSDK-2.3.3/extras/m2repository/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.0.0/baseLibrary-3.0.0.jar
file:/O:/AndroidSDK-2.3.3/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.0.0/baseLibrary-3.0.0.pom
file:/O:/AndroidSDK-2.3.3/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.0.0/baseLibrary-3.0.0.jar
file:/O:/AndroidSDK-2.3.3/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.0.0/baseLibrary-3.0.0.pom
file:/O:/AndroidSDK-2.3.3/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.0.0/baseLibrary-3.0.0.jar
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.0.0/baseLibrary-3.0.0.pom
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.0.0/baseLibrary-3.0.0.jar
https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk-releases/raw/master/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.0.0/baseLibrary-3.0.0.pom
https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk-releases/raw/master/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.0.0/baseLibrary-3.0.0.jar
Required by:
project :sample-custom-objects > com.android.databinding:library:1.3.1
project :sample-custom-objects > com.android.databinding:adapters:1.3.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this lines to your module-level build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.android.databinding:library:1.3.1'
implementation 'com.android.databinding:adapters:1.3.1'
```