# Could not find com.android.databinding:library:3.1.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-databinding

I upgraded to Android Studio 3.1.1 and trying to clone a project from GitHub but unable to run it due to the following error

```
Could not find com.android.databinding:library:3.1.1.
```

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48377267/could-not-find-com-android-databindingbaselibrary3-0-0) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49630048/android-support-plugin-errors-after-upgrading-android-studio-to-3-1-0) but unable to resolve the issue. The latter suggests to update to the 3.2 canary 10 version but is there no way to resolve this in 3.1.1?

EDIT after Android Team suggestion

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
      google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can add your project level gradle file ,please verify you are not missing **jcenter()** in your gradle file

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: I just added my project level gradle file

Comment: So issue fixed?

Comment: Nope, jcenter() was present before posting the issue

Comment: There was no google() in the allprojects{} section which caused the problem somehow anyway it's resolved thanks @Android Team. I think the problem was because the project I was trying to clone had old gradle plugin.

Comment: But here you're referring to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0` instead of `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1`. I have `3.1.1` working after upgrading to "Android Studio 3.1.1" (I really thing that the versioning is unrelated, but I may be wrong), but I also upgraded the project to use Gradle 4.4

Comment: Having the same problem but jcenter() is already added in my project level gradle file. Please help me.\

Comment: Adding google() in repositories helped me. Here is more info: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html

Answer (score 1):

**just add google() to your project level gradle file, and it will fix the issue**

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()        //<-----This line
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()     //<-----This line
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thanks for your answer. Try to add an explanation, code only answers are not encouraged [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)